# VB.NET : Add/Edit/Delete an XElement inside XML file with XDocument

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have to make an app where I access elements from a XML file, and then **add-modify-delete** some of those and update theses elements back inside the XML. I managed to load the elements with **XDocument** from the XML file, however I'm having a hard understanding how to save changes to the XML file with **XDocument**.

*myfile.xml*

```
<root>
   <functions>
      <function name="foo">
         <description> "foofoofoo" </description>
      </function>
      <function name="bar">
         <description> "barbarbar" </description>
      </function>
   </functions>
...
</root>
```

So far this is what I have been trying with **XDocument** but it doesn't actually save anything.

*app.vd* for adding an element

```
...
xml = XDocument.Load(pathToXmlFile)
functions = From f In xml.Descendants("functions") Select f

functions.Append(New XElement("function", 
                              New XAttribute("name", newName), 
                              New XElement("description", newDescription)))
xml.Save(pathToXmlFile)
...
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It looks to me like `functions` is still a selected sequence.  You might need to take `functions.Single` to get the functions node, and then you'll be able to append to that.  Do you have `Option Strict On`?

Comment: I would use : xml.Descendants("functions").FirstOrDefault().Add(New XElement("function", 
                              New XAttribute("name", newName), 
                              New XElement("description", newDescription)));

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlSerialization to get objects into concrete classes and modify and write back, quite trivially

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
```

Xml model

```vb
<XmlRoot("root")>
Partial Public Class Root
    <XmlArrayItem("function")>
    Public Property functions() As List(Of [Function])
End Class

Partial Public Class [Function]
    <XmlElement("description")>
    Public Property Description() As String
    <XmlAttribute("name")>
    Public Property Name() As String
End Class
```

Read, modify, write

```vb
Dim xml As Root
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Root))

' read
Using sr As New StreamReader("myfile.xml")
    xml = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(sr), Root)
End Using

' modify
xml.functions.Add(
    New [Function]() With {
        .Name = "newName",
        .Description = "newDescription"})

' write
Using sw As New StreamWriter("myfile.xml")
    serializer.Serialize(sw, xml)
End Using
```